# Vue JS prop in component always undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `<select>` component. Once I select a category I need to get the ID and also a boolean which checks if the category has a subcategory, if it does, I make an API call to fetch the subcategories.

Parent template:

```
<material-selectcat v-model="catId" name="category" id="selcat">
  <option 
    v-for="cat in cats" 
    :value="cat.cat_id" 
    :subcat="cat.has_subCat" 
    v-text="cat.category_name"
  ></option>
</material-selectcat>
```

Child component:

```
<template>
  <select><slot></slot></select>
</template>

<script>

    export default {

      props: ['value', 'subcat'],
      watch: {
        watcher: function() {}
      },
      computed: {
        watcher: function() {
          this.relaod(this.value);
          this.fetchSubCategories(this.value, this.subcat);
        }
      },
      methods: {
        relaod: function(value) {

          var select = $(this.$el);

          select.val(value || this.value);
          select.material_select('destroy');
          select.material_select();
        },
        fetchSubCategories: function(val, sub) {
          var mdl = this;
          var catID = val || this.value;
          console.log("sub: " + sub);

          mdl.$emit("reset-subcats");

          if (catID) {
            if (sub == 1) {
              if ($('.subdropdown').is(":visible") == true) {
                $('.subdropdown').fadeOut();
              }
            } else {
              axios.get(URL.API + '/subcategories/' + catID)
                .then(function(response) {
                  response = response.data.subcatData;
                  response.unshift({
                    subcat_id: '0',
                    subcategory_name: 'All Subcategories'
                  });
                  mdl.$emit("update-subcats", response);

                  $('.subdropdown').fadeIn();
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                  if (error.response.data) {

                    swal({
                      title: "Something went wrong",
                      text: "Please try again",
                      type: "error",
                      html: false
                    });

                  }
                });
            }
          } else {
            if ($('.subdropdown').is(":visible") == true) {
              $('.subdropdown').fadeOut();
            }
          }
        }
      },
      mounted: function() {

        var vm = this;
        var select = $(this.$el);

        select
          .val(this.value)
          .on('change', function() {
            vm.$emit('input', this.value);
          });

        select.material_select();
      },
      updated: function() {

        this.relaod();
      },
      destroyed: function() {

        $(this.$el).material_select('destroy');
      }
    }
</script>
```

But inside the `fetchSubCategories()` function this line always returns `undefined`:

```
console.log("sub: " + sub);
```

If I check the **Vue Devtools** tab in my Chrome inspector, I can see that all of the data exists:

```
cat_id:0
category_name:"All Subcategories"
has_subCat:0
```

But why doesnt `has_subCat` get passed as a prop?

Comment: You pass the prop on the `option`, whereas you declare the prop on the `select`.

Comment: @EricGuan sorry I dont follow? I can read all values beside ``:subcat="cat.has_subCat"``

Comment: The code you've written states that `material-selectcat` is expecting a prop named `subcat`. Meaning the template expects `<material-selectcat :subcat="(variable containing subcat)">`. But you are passing the prop to an HTML tag which does nothing, not a vue component. Because v-model gives you the selected catId, you can simply find the cat by id, and check if it has a subcat

Comment: But ``:value="cat.cat_id"`` is also inside the option and that returns a value

Comment: That is vue handling the form input bindings for you. props are strictly for vue components. value is also a standard html attribute.

Comment: Could you give me an example on how I could find ``cat`` by id so I can check the value of ``has_subCat`` ? That would solve my problem

Comment: `var has_subCat = this.cats.find(cat=>cat.id == this.catId).has_subCat`

Comment: Adding ``var has_subCat = this.cats.find(cat=>cat.id == this.catId).has_subCat;`` inside ``fetchSubCategories()`` gives me the error: **Error in callback for watcher "value": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `subcat` prop is `undefined` because you are not passing it to the component. But, a `subcat` prop doesn't make much sense anyway, since you want to check the value for each `option` in the `select` which could all be different.

If you compose the options inside of the component definition:

```javascript
// child component script
props: ['value', 'options'],
```

```html
// child component template
<template>
  <select>
    <slot>
      <option 
        v-for="option in options" 
        :key="option.id"
        :value="option.id" 
        :subcat="option.subcat" 
        v-text="option.text"
      ></option>
    </slot>
  </select>
</template>
```

And then pass a correctly formatted `options` prop to the component:

```javascript
// parent component script
computed: {
  options() {
    return this.cats.map((cat) => {
      return {
        id: cat.cat_id,
        subcat: cat.has_subcat,
        text: cat.category_name
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
// parent component template
<material-selectcat v-model="catId" :options="options" name="category" id="selcat">
</material-selectcat>
```

Then, you could get the correct `subcat` value for any option's corresponding `value` by referencing the `options` prop in the `fetchSubCategories` method:

```
fetchSubCategories: function(val) {
  var mdl = this;
  var catID = val || this.value;
  var sub = (this.options.find(o => o.id === val) || {}).subcat;
  ...
```

---

The reason your `value` prop is defined in your code is that you are using the `v-model` directive on the component tag. [The `v-model` directive is just syntactic sugar](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events) for `:value="something" @input="something = $event.target.value"`. Since you've specified `catID` as the `v-model`, that will be passed to your component as the `value` prop.